# Quickblox occupent Ids

Tags: android, quickblox

I want to make group chat rooms without specifying the IDs of the users and when a user create a new account I get to decide which group chat should he joins, the app is developed for Android, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: add some other info or Source code ..

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Quickblox "Update group dialog" documentation](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Update_group_dialog), "User can update group chat dialog name, add new occupants or leave this group chat. To add more occupants use push operator. To leave group chat (remove yourself) - use pull all operator"

```
QBRequestUpdateBuilder requestBuilder = new QBRequestUpdateBuilder();
requestBuilder.push("occupants_ids", 378); // add another users
// requestBuilder.pullAll("occupants_ids", 22); // Remove yourself (user with ID 22)

QBGroupChatManager groupChatManager = QBChatService.getInstance().getGroupChatManager();
groupChatManager.updateDialog("53aac645535c12bd3b008a40", "Team room", requestBuilder, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBDialog>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QBDialog dialog, Bundle args) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(List<String> errors) {

    }
});
```

Keep in mind, you need the proper permissions to edit a dialog (i.e. be a member of the private group dialog). If you need to create  a brand new dialog, check out the [Quickblox "Create new dialog" documentation](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Create_new_dialog).

Comment: Please can you tell me how to add permissions

Answer (score 0):

You can create public group chats for example, so any user can join this group chat

http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Create_new_group_chat_dialog

```
dialog.setType(QBDialogType.PUBLIC_GROUP);
```

Comment: I want it to be private but add users to it programmatically